# How can I go about diagnosing a poor performing Rails application running on mysql?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, performance

I've taken over the maintenance of a Rails 2.3.4 application running on ruby 1.8.7 and mysql. The application is a modified Radiant CMS 0.8.1 site with custom extensions. Currently, the production environment is experiencing frequent periods of slow and sometimes no responsiveness. During these times I've noticed that the mysql CPU usage jumps through the roof. The web site has an international audience and at the time of it's creation scaling the site was not taken into consideration. Currently, the user base is at around 4600 and growing. What are some initial steps I can take to diagnose the poor performance in both Rails and mysql?

Thanks,
Mike

Answer (score 3):

While not Rails-specific, I'd recommend using the MySQL [slow query log](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/slow-query-log.html) and tracking those back to the queries your Rails application is sending (check `log/production.log`).

Comment: After you find the slow queries, you can use EXPLAIN to determine why they are so slow (I'm guessing just missing indexes if these are queries generated by activerecord)

Answer (score 1):

The last place I contracted used a tool called query_reviewer. It's a Rails plugin that in development mode analyzes every query and gives you warnings in the UI letting you know any possible issues. I liked it because you didn't have to switch back and forth between your app and log or other testing tools.

https://github.com/dsboulder/query_reviewer

Another helpful tool is New Relic - it's free for developing if you're just using it on your local. It analyzes more than just SQL, including view rendering and other potential efficiency issues.

http://newrelic.com/

Comment: If you use query_reviewer, check github for newer forks than the one linked here.